How does np.random.integers() move the current rng seed?
I am trying to preserve the sequence of a random number generator as carefully as possible. However the following code shows that there seem some problem with the progression of the current random seed.
I do not understand the reason the first two loops give the same answer for random_arr.
import numpy as np

def train_test_split(X,rint):
    print('rint = ',rint)
    return X

def index_split(X,rng):
    X_train = train_test_split(X, rng.integers(65536))
    return X_train

def new_rng():
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
    return rng

seed = 1234
n_params = 4

extranls = [0, 1, 2]
X = [0]

print('np.__version__ = ',np.__version__)
for ind, extran in enumerate(extranls):
    print('\n\n----------')
    print('rng #: ',ind)
    RNG = new_rng()
    X_train = index_split(X, RNG)
    for i in range(extran):
        print('Extra: rng.integers(65536) = ',RNG.integers(65536))

    initial_parameters = np.zeros(n_params, dtype=np.float32)
    random_arr = RNG.random(n_params)
    print('extran = ',extran)
    print('random_arr is ',random_arr)

# 
# np.__version__ =  1.26.4
# 
# 
# ----------
# rng #:  0
# rint =  64182
# extran =  0
# random_arr is  [0.38019574 0.92324623 0.26169242 0.31909706]
# 
# 
# ----------
# rng #:  1
# rint =  64182
# Extra: rng.integers(65536) =  64008
# extran =  1
# random_arr is  [0.38019574 0.92324623 0.26169242 0.31909706]
# 
# 
# ----------
# rng #:  2
# rint =  64182
# Extra: rng.integers(65536) =  64008
# Extra: rng.integers(65536) =  64745
# extran =  2
# random_arr is  [0.92324623 0.26169242 0.31909706 0.11809123]


The first and second loops gives [0.38019574 0.92324623 0.26169242 0.31909706]

This question is much easier to debug if you set extranls = range(10). It looks like RNG.random discards several bits (2 bytes?) produced by the RNG in certain cases.

If you need to preserve a single RNG's state, you could pull a single integer from that RNG to use as a seed for another RNG, and call integers on the new "sub" RNG.

What OS and NumPy version are you on?

I reproduced this on with Numpy 1.26.4 on Windows 10. Has anyone found a system where this behaviour is not reproduced?

The algorithm underlying the default PCG64 BitGenerator generates 64-bit values, but generating a number from 0 to 65535 doesn't need 64-bit random values. Most requests for random integers don't need 64-bit random values. So, NumPy has an optimization. To serve requests where 32 bits suffice, the PCG64 BitGenerator splits its underlying 64-bit output to generate 32-bit values 2 at a time.
Calling RNG.integers(65536) inside index_split generates 2 32-bit values, uses one to generate the output you requested, and caches the other. Calling it again uses the cached value, without advancing the underlying state. Calling RNG.random(n_params) can't use the cache, so it behaves the same whether you call it immediately after index_split, or after making a single extra RNG.integers(65536) call.
You can see the responsible code in the NumPy source repository, particularly here, here, and here.
Note that this is all implementation details. The docs mention that this kind of thing may happen, but do not promise that it will happen.
